# Question about the correct data structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a requests table.

for each request there are 2 people in different roles related to it and the details should be kept exactly the same.

the details of people appear in another table.

Is it correct to place 2 key fields in the request table for each person  that link to the person table

or it is best to place the key field in the persons table?
(each person can have only one request)

Would you do that:

[image]

Or like that

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A typical solution to your design would be to maintain three tables.  In addition to the persons and requests table, which would exist to store data about people and the requests themselves, there would be a third *junction* table, which would exist to maintain relationships between people and requests.  Here is what that junction table might look like:

```
person_id | request_id
1         | 1
2         | 1
3         | 2
4         | 2
```

The requirement of only one person having one request can be enforced using a unique constraint on the `person_id` in the junction table.

Restricting each request to only two people is a bit more tricky, but could be accomplished using a before insert trigger.

Comment: Are you sure the third table is necessary?

Comment: It is necessary if you want to use the standard solution for your problem.

Comment: There should also be a rule that every person is in a different role, let's say that for every request there should be a manager and a secretary.
And this rule is not enforced in your solution

Comment: And this requirement was never mentioned in your initial question, and is still not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Second row: "for each request there are 2 people in different roles related to it "

Answer (score 0):

Yes, three tables.

Try something like this:

```
use tempdb

create table Person
(
   Id int primary key, 
   Name varchar(200) 
)

create table Request
(
  Id int primary key
)


create table Request_Person
(
  RequestId int not null references Request,
  PersonId int not null references Person,
  RequestRole int not null,
  constraint ck_max_two_people_per_request check (RequestRole in (1,2)),
  constraint pk_Request_Person primary key (RequestId, PersonId),
  constraint ak_Request_Person unique(PersonId),
  constraint uq_Request_RequestRole unique (RequestId,RequestRole)
)

go

insert into Request(id) values  (1),(2),(3) 

insert into Person(id,name) values (1,'Alice'),(2,'Fred'),(3,'Jo')

insert into Request_Person(RequestId,PersonId,RequestRole)
values (1,1,1),(1,2,2)

insert into Request_Person(RequestId,PersonId,RequestRole)
values (2,2,1) --Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'ak_Request_Person'

insert into Request_Person(RequestId,PersonId,RequestRole)
values (1,3,3) --The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_max_two_people_per_request"
```

Comment: Why is the third table necessary?

Comment: With just two tables I don't think you can enforce the rules you specified.

Comment: What rule can not be enforced?